# Translate real mode memory access instrution to AT&T syntax

Tags: x86, x86-16, att, real-mode

How do I translate the following x86 real mode instruction to gas AT&T syntax?

```
cmp word [es:di], 0x1234
```

Comment: The obvious way would be to assemble with `nasm -felf32` and disassemble with `objdump -d` to see the syntax.  The same instruction has the same syntax in 32-bit mode, just different machine code.

Comment: @PeterCordes: That makes a lot of sense, thanks.